# How generate layout dynamically from mysql?

Tags: android, sql, forms, layout, dynamic

Is it possible to create a layout for an application on android from fields in a database?

I have a table in the database that contains questions and I want to generate a "form" or "layout" depending on the data that is in that table.

For example, I have question one:
[image]

as we see in the table I have the column "tipo_pregunta" which is what it will say if it is an input, checkbox, textarea, etc.
I wanted to know if it is possible or if you know some guide from which I can learn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Of course, you can generate layout dynamically.

1. Create layout(LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc) object.
2. Iterate database result
3. Create a view on checking your "tipo_pregunta" value. like(TextView, Checkbox, RadioButton etc)
4. Add this created view in your layout object - **layoutObj.add(viewObj)**;
5. Repeat steps 3 & 4 till your database result count.